# Best Database for Blog Application (Relational - SQL vs NoSQL)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, nosql

I am starting developing a new application for blogs in .net mvc. I am working on relational databases (Sql Server) from past 3+ years, these days i am seeing many articles on No Sql databases too and many articles says that nosql/graphdb is a future so i just want to know which database will be better for a blog kind of application relational or nosql?

I want to go with nosql for learning purpose but there are too many nosql databases like- cassandra, couch, mongo, raven, hbase, neo4j etc so please suggest which db i should choose for blog app-

1. Relational or No Sql
2. If no Sql then which No Sql

Hoping for some positive responses.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically use SQL or noSQL approach depends on such factors as how your data model (I mean your tables in SQL or lists in no SQL) changes and what will you do with it when you have lots of data.

If you data model pretty much known and changes not often, plus you have really difficult logic to work with it (and validate ofcourse) than I usually **use SQL** approach, becouse it's easier to **keep your data consistency**.

The next problem that you faces is huge amount of data. With SQL approach you have to build **DWH** (data warehouse) if you want to query your data fast. With noSQL approach in theory you can easily spread your data of different servers.

About blog - you definatly don't know right now what kind of model you will have in the end. And you wouldn't create tricky reports i gess. So it's ok to use noSQL model.

About your question what noSQL DB select i recommend to look at [brightstardb](http://brightstardb.com/) becouse you can map your model with EF and it will be easier to develop. Another noSQL db that you can look at is  [Azure DocumentDB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/) becouse it's MS approach to noSQL, but it available only in Azure right now and it has no stand alone version.

Comment: Or you can use Amazon's DynamoDb (LOL at how close Azure's name is to DynamoDB). AWS is the leader for a reason. Appsync / Amplify framework is easy to use and uses DynamoDB (NOSQL) by default.

Comment: @EvanErickson is that an advertisement? (: ty anyway

Comment: Advertisement, no. A recommendation. I think AWS is the best. Azure is probably great too though.

Comment: @EvanErickson sure  thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have been using mongo nosql for smaller web applications. Mongo nosql would  work really well for such an application.
Easy to connect to, and easy to get into since its object related.
Just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @Bb91 for the opinion. I will check mongo in detail.

Comment: Happy to give my two cents :)